# Is there a prime number that is larger than the product of preceding two prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_i$ be sequence of prime number starting from 2.

Is there a prime number $p_k$ $\ni$ $p_k > p_{k-1} \times p_{k-2}$.

If $\nexists$ $p_k$ $\ni$ $p_k > p_{k-1} \times p_{k-2}$, could you please provide a proof?

Comment: [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate)

Comment: May be I am wrong, but I think Bertrand's postulate says $p_{n+1} < 2p_n$. However I would like to know if $p_{n+1} < p_n \times p_{n-1}$ is true for all prime numbers.

Comment: $p_{n-1}\geq 2$ for all $n\geq 2$, so ...

Comment: Thank you, I got it!

Comment: A brute force search in Mathematica for at least the first 50,000 primes says not. `Total[Table[
  If[Prime[k]*Prime[k + 1] < Prime[k + 2], 1, 0], {k, 1, 50000}]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2p_{k-1}>p_k$ (Bertrand). So if $p_k>p_{k-1}q$ with $q$ prime then $2p_{k-1}>p_{k-1}q,$ implying $2>q$, which is absurd.

Comment: Bertrand's "Postulate" dates to the early 1800's. The first rigorous proof was by Minkowski. At the age of 18 Erdos found a simple but subtle proof based on the possible prime divisors of $\binom {2p}{p}.$

Answer (score 0):

There is already one:

$ 3 > 2 $

But after that, there is no other.

Comment: @RamasamyKandasamy

Comment: But 1 is not a prime number.